# Excel 2010 keeps crashing after more than X number of loops

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro (below) that is designed to run 150,000 iterations before ending. However, after I run the code for more than 1,000 iterations, Excel goes to "Not responding" mode, and then crashes. I've left it for more than 12 hours, but it does not get any better. The code has previously been used to run the first 100,000 iterations, and is needed to run up to 1,048,576 iterations, in stages of 250,000.

The crashes also bring down Outlook, IE, as well as Chrome (although I've stopped running them at the same time, but still crashes).

If I run the code via F8, or to a checkpoint via F5, the code runs fine. However, that is impractical for another 948,576 iterations.

Any suggestions on how to resolve the issue, so it doesn't crash constantly?

The system specs are:
Excel 2010
i5 (3rd gen)
8 GB RAM

Code:

```
Dim a As Variant
Dim b As Variant
Dim c As Variant
Dim d As Variant
Dim e As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Double
Dim strResult As Double

a = 1
b = 100001

While b <= 250000

    While a <= 12

        If a = 1 Then

            If Cells(b, 14) = "EEEE" Then
                Cells(b, a) = 1234
            ElseIf Cells(b, 14) = "ZYXW" Then
                Cells(b, a) = 2468
            ElseIf Cells(b, 14) = "AAAA" Then
                Cells(b, a) = 3579
            ElseIf Cells(b, 14) = "BBBB" Then
                Cells(b, a) = 9764
            ElseIf Cells(b, 14) = "DDDD" Then
                Cells(b, a) = 8631
            Else
                Cells(b, a) = "ZZZZ"
            End If

        ElseIf a = 2 Then

            If Cells(b, 15) = 5 Then
                Cells(b, a) = "JPY"
            ElseIf Cells(b, 15) = 4 Then
                Cells(b, a) = "GBP"
            ElseIf Cells(b, 15) = 3 Then
                Cells(b, a) = "CHF"
            ElseIf Cells(b, 15) = 2 Then
                Cells(b, a) = "USD"
            ElseIf Cells(b, 15) = 1 Then
                Cells(b, a) = "EUR"
            Else
                Cells(b, a) = "YYYY"
            End If

        ElseIf a = 3 Then

            If Cells(b, 16) = 10234 Then
                Cells(b, a) = "A27Z2"
            ElseIf Cells(b, 16) = 10420 Then
                Cells(b, a) = "B28Y"
            ElseIf Cells(b, 16) = 10432 Then
                Cells(b, a) = "C29X"
            ElseIf Cells(b, 16) = 18953 Then
                Cells(b, a) = "D30W"
            ElseIf Cells(b, 16) = 21048 Then
                Cells(b, a) = "E31V"
            ElseIf Cells(b, 16) = 36542 Then
                Cells(b, a) = "F32U"
            ElseIf Cells(b, 16) = 36954 Then
                Cells(b, a) = "G33T"
            ElseIf Cells(b, 16) = 65425 Then
                Cells(b, a) = "H34S"
            ElseIf Cells(b, 16) = 75963 Then
                Cells(b, a) = "I35R"
            ElseIf Cells(b, 16) = 84563 Then
                Cells(b, a) = "J36Q"
            Else
                Cells(b, a) = "XXXX"
            End If

        ElseIf a = 4 Then

            strResult = 1
            For i = 1 To Len(Cells(b, 18))
                Select Case Asc(Mid(Cells(b, 18), i, 1))
                    Case 65 To 90:
                        strResult = strResult + Asc(Mid(Cells(b, 18), i, 1)) - 64
                    Case Else
                        strResult = strResult + Mid(Cells(b, 18), i, 1)
                End Select
            Next

            j = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A1:A" & b), Range("A" & b), Range("B1:B" & b), Range("B" & b))

            Cells(b, a) = Cells(b, 1) & " - " & Cells(b, 2) & strResult & " - " & j

        ElseIf a = 5 Then

            Cells(b, a) = Cells(b, 17)

        ElseIf a = 6 Then

            If Cells(b, 19) = "SB" Then
                Cells(b, a) = "Sub"
            ElseIf Cells(b, 19) = "RD" Then
                Cells(b, a) = "Red"
            Else
                Cells(b, a) = "XXXX"
            End If

        ElseIf a >= 7 Then

            Cells(b, a) = Cells(b, a + 13)

        End If

        a = a + 1

    Wend

    b = b + 1
    a = 1

Wend

    Columns("M:Q").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("N:V").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Comment: 1) Check what's crashing. Are you using too many resources, or is the usage ok but the macro takes so long that Excel goes unresponsive, then you crash Excel by trying to get it to respond? If it's just a very long macro and you want to be able to check its status, consider adding in a `DoEvents` every once in a while. 2) Speed up the code. There are lots of references to `Cells` here, which will be slower than storing and accessing an array. Check out our sister site Code Review for more help on optimizing.

Comment: @Mikegrann 1) Resource usage runs between 2 - 6% when idle. When I'm running the code, it shoots up to between 75 - 95%, with 3 of the 4 processors running full out for maybe 10 seconds. it then drops down to about 25%, but is unresponsive. If I click on it, use Crtl+Brk, or ESC, the system crashes. 2) Not sure how I would use an array in this. could you advise?

Comment: 32 bit or 64bit version of Excel?

Comment: add `DoEvents` before each `wend`

Comment: @MatsLind I would think it is 32 bit, based on the normal usage within the company (non-dev, non-IT, normally used for small calcs)

Comment: Stop playing around with the cells and use a variant array. I'll try to work something up.

Comment: @GaryEvans probably just on the outer loop, max. The inner loop only goes through 12 items, and it should execute *relatively* quickly. No sense  surrounding that much processor time to `DoEvents`. I'd probably do something more like run `DoEvents` once every X number of loops of the outer loop. Tune it for reasonable responsiveness (whatever definition you might have of that).

Comment: Then your memory resourses are quite scarce, your theroetical limit is 2GB but practically 32-bit Excel starts to misbehave already when it has used up like 1.5 GB. Look in this blogpost on how to check memory usage for the applicattion: http://msexcelandvba.blogspot.se/2016/07/32-bit-excel-stay-away-from-its-memory.html

Comment: This looks like an XY problem to me. Can you forget all this for a moment and explain what are you trying to achieve with this humongous code?

Comment: A lot of good comments here. I will reiterate the use of a variant array and `DoEvents`. I have used both with very good results. The one caution is the overuse of `DoEvents` as you can fill up your stack with too many calls. I've never run into that specific issue though, and I've used it pretty liberally in a few macros.

Comment: @Kyle - I don't think `DoEvents` is necessary and this (as written) should execute in several seconds; certainly less than 10.

Comment: @SiddharthRout The initial data is derived from one system, and it needs to be transformed into the layout, format, and data needed for a second system. the second system can't do the transformation itself, and doing it by hand is a nightmare. The code will need to be run a few dozen times, on spreadsheets with 950,000+ rows of data in each. (It was planned by a group of people who can barely use Outlook)  :(

Comment: Why is `strResult` assigned an integer?

Comment: @Clauric Did you check the memory usage? To minimize usage, have no other sheets open, avoid cell formulas and formatting!

Comment: @Jeeped it is assigned an integer as the value will be a whole number between 1 and 26. It is designed to turn an uppercase letter into a number.

Comment: @Jeeped, probably right on the `DoEvents` not being necessary, but I question whether this can execute that fast "as written". Certainly under 10 seconds with the same logic, but using arrays.

Comment: @Clauric Less important of a concern, but I would recommend changing all the ElseIfs to Case statements also.

Comment: @MatsLind no other sheets open, no formulae within the sheet, and no other Office based product open. when running, Excel jumps to about 704,000K memory (according to task manager), but drops down to about 50,000K otherwise. As an example, having this page open is using 150,000K

Comment: Why is the Countifs based on ranges like `Range("A1:A" & b)` when you start `b` at 100001?

Comment: @jeeped there is already 100,000 rows done using this code. It crashes at about row 105,000. The count still needs to start at 0. In an ideal world, the code will start at 2, and run to 1,048,576

Comment: @Clauric  does it stay at 700 MB? Where does it stand when it crashes?

Comment: @MatsLind When it crashes, it drops back down to 50,000K. I assume it is MB, but giving exactly what it says in Task Manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the variant in-memory processing I discussed earlier in comments. While it is actually a little slower that the formula approach offered earlier, it is also more complete; in particular using a dictionary object to calculate the countifs.

```
Option Explicit

Sub bigRun()
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim c As Variant, d As Variant, e As Variant  '<~~??????
    Dim vals As Variant
    Dim ab As String, strResult As String
    Dim dABs As Object

    appTGGL

    Set dABs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dABs.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        vals = .Range("A100001:Z250000").Value2
        For b = 100001 To 250000
            For a = 1 To 12
                Select Case a
                    Case 1
                        Select Case vals(b - 100000, 14)
                            Case "EEEE"
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = 1234
                            Case "ZYXW"
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = 2468
                            Case "AAAA"
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = 3579
                            Case "BBBB"
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = 9764
                            Case "DDDD"
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = 8631
                            Case Else
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "ZZZZ"
                        End Select
                    Case 2
                        Select Case vals(b - 100000, 15)
                            Case 5
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "JPY"
                            Case 4
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "GBP"
                            Case 3
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "CHF"
                            Case 2
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "USD"
                            Case 1
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "EUR"
                            Case Else
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "YYYY"
                        End Select
                    Case 3
                        Select Case vals(b - 100000, 16)
                            Case 10234
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "A27Z2"
                            Case 10420
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "B28Y"
                            Case 10432
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "C29X"
                            Case 18953
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "D30W"
                            Case 21048
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "E31V"
                            Case 36542
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "F32U"
                            Case 36954
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "G33T"
                            Case 65425
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "H34S"
                            Case 75963
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "I35R"
                            Case 84563
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "J36Q"
                            Case Else
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "XXXX"
                        End Select
                    Case 4
                        ab = Join(Array(vals(b - 100000, 1), vals(b - 100000, 2)), ChrW(8203))
                        If dABs.exists(ab) Then
                            j = dABs.Item(ab) + 1
                        Else
                            j = 1
                        End If
                        dABs.Item(ab) = j

                        strResult = 1
                        For i = 1 To Len(vals(b - 100000, 18))
                            Select Case Asc(Mid(vals(b - 100000, 18), i, 1))
                                Case 65 To 90:
                                    strResult = strResult + Asc(Mid(vals(b - 100000, 18), i, 1)) - 64
                                Case Else
                                    strResult = strResult + Mid(vals(b - 100000, 18), i, 1)
                            End Select
                        Next

                        vals(b - 100000, a) = Join(Array(vals(b - 100000, 1), _
                                                         vals(b - 100000, 2), _
                                                         strResult, j), _
                                                   Chr(32) & Chr(45) & Chr(32))
                    Case 5
                        vals(b - 100000, a) = vals(b - 100000, 17)
                    Case 6
                        Select Case vals(b - 100000, 19)
                            Case "SB"
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "Sub"
                            Case "RD"
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "Red"
                            Case Else
                                vals(b - 100000, a) = "XXXX"
                        End Select
                    Case 7 To 12
                        vals(b - 100000, a) = vals(b - 100000, a + 13)
                End Select
            Next a
        Next b

        .Range("A100001").Resize(UBound(vals, 1), UBound(vals, 2)) = vals

        '.Columns("M:Q").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        '.Columns("N:V").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    End With

    dABs.RemoveAll: Set dABs = Nothing
    appTGGL bTGGL:=False

End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
        .EnableEvents = bTGGL
        .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
        .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

[image]

My sample data is available temporarily [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Fix_Big_Loop_Variants.xlsb). Elapsed time on an old i5 business class laptop that closely mirrors your own configuration was ~13 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

This just took me less than 5 seconds to populate `10` columns out of `12`. It may be because most of my sheet was empty but none the less, if you switch off calculations/screenupdating, it will be faster.

The only two columns that it doesn't populate is `C` and `D`. You cannot use a formula approach for it as it exceeds the `If` condition requirements. You can write a small loop for those 2.

There is no need to loop from row `100001` to `250000` and from Columns `1` to `12`. You can enter a formula in those cells in one go. Here is an example

```
Sub Sample()
    '~~> When a = 1 i.e Col A
    range("A100001:A250000").Formula = "=IF(N100001=""EEEE"",""1234"",IF(N100001=""ZYXW"",""2468"",IF(N100001=""AAAA"",""3579"",IF(N100001=""BBBB"",""9764"",IF(N100001=""DDDD"",""8631"",""ZZZZ"")))))"

    range("B100001:B250000").Formula = "=IF(O100001=""5"",""JPY"",IF(O100001=""4"",""GBP"",IF(O100001=""3"",""CHF"",IF(O100001=""2"",""USD"",IF(O100001=""1"",""EUR"",""YYYY"")))))"

    '3,4 This needs to be coded

    range("E100001:E250000").Value = range("Q100001:Q250000").Value

    range("F100001:F250000").Formula = "=IF(S100001=""SB"",""Sub"",IF(S100001=""RD"",""Red"",""XXXX""))"

    For i = 7 To 12
        range(Cells(100001, i), Cells(250000, i)).Formula = "=" & Cells(100001, i + 13).Address
    Next i
End Sub
```

When I ran this code, this is what I got

[image]

Comment: looks like a very nice code. From my reading, I would then need to convert the formulae to absolute values. Is that correct?

Comment: It it again a simple and single line of code... `Range("A100001:L25000").Value=Range("A100001:L25000").Value` You can put this at the end of the code :)

Comment: @Siddarth Rout Didnt you forget a "0", shouldn't it be "L250000"?

Comment: @MatsLind: Yup I did :)

Comment: @Jeeped: You have option explicit on? 'Dim i as long'

Comment: @SiddharthRout I tested the code out, and it works for 90% of the values. The only error is in the final section, where it is just returning the value from cells(2,i+13) for every cell

Comment: @Clauric: That is because that what we are asking it to do ;) Simply amend that and it will work